# AsciiDoc, How to set an attribute with javascript or similar

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I want to dynamically display a certain server status in an asciidoc (rendered in gitlab)

Something like

```
:status-server-1: 1

ifeval::[{status-server-1} == 1]
image::green_dot.png[green_dot,20,20]
endif::[]
```

Now how to dynamically set the attribute?

Is there a way the change the attribute with javascript or similar?

Answer (score 1):

`asciidoctor` doesn't process JavaScript. It transforms Asciidoc markup to HTML (or other formats). JavaScript only comes into play when the resulting HTML is loaded into a browser.

It would be possible to run a JavaScript program before you run `asciidoctor` to determine the server status and set an environment variable that could then be used during `asciidoctor` processing. For example:

```
STATUS=`node status.js`; asciidoctor -a server_status="$STATUS" <file.adoc>
```

A different approach would be to use [Docinfo](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/docinfo/) files to add custom JS or CSS. Custom JS would allow you to perform an XHR request to discover the current server status and then adjust the classes/styles/images needed to reflect that status.

Comment: Thank you.
I tried using a "++++" Passthrough Block to add JS but the script tags and the id in for example "<p id="serverStatus"></p>" gets deleted in the gitlab preview.
Something is filtering the input.

Comment: GitLab and GitHub both filter out any "injected" JavaScript to prevent malicious code from doing things you don't expect. You'd likely have to setup CI/CD to run a script to define an environment variable and then run `asciidoctor`.